# Can't run my Spring boot app via Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

I am creating a spring boot app in Eclipse and it is all barebones right now.

I used the example pom from the spring boot reference guide shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Package as an executable jar -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Next I created a basic Application.java class like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication 
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

And I this point I want to just run it to see if it succeeds, so I go into Run Configurations and create a new one with the goal "spring-boot:run".

But when I run it, I get an exception:
ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication

This doesn't make sense to me, because the Eclipse IDE is not showing any errors on the class indicating there is a problem locating SpringApplication.

One thing to note, I did have to do something special to get my spring jars included in my project, because my dev environment cannot access public maven repos I have a local repo with all these jars, and in the project Build Path's Libraries section I had to "Add Variable" pointing to all the base spring framework jars to get my project to see them. Before I did this it couldn't locate the jars in Eclipse.

Now I am confused why it can't find them when I run it?

*EDIT* One thing I notice is when it creates the jar in the \target folder, there is no lib folder in there, it never includes the jars from my project.

Answer (score -1):

You need not take any pain.
Just simply go to http://start.spring.io/
Name your group and artifact id, add what all dependecies you need for your project.
Simply click on **Generate Project**
You will have the download of a zip file, extract the folder.
Import the project in your eclipse.

HAPPY CODING !!

Comment: stil gettin run configuration IDE not detecting main file.